# Generate a word document with excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I've modificated the code following the last advices that I've recived.
However I still can't generate the new word document using my VBA code from Excel.

I would like that Excel will able to modificate text content and generate a new document that it will open when I click on the button.

Here what I've done [image]

And this is the code and it says I have a "91 error" for the line `worddoc.Close SaveChanges:=False`

there the code:

```
Sub export_Automatisation_MT() 'nom du maccro
    Dim wordapp As Word.Application
    Dim worddoc As Word.Document

    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.application") 'crée une application word
    Set worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Open("O:\Projets\RAZAN BORKI\01 MEMOIRE TECHNIQUE.docx") 'document de base

    Call traitement_champs(worddoc) 'traite le texte contenu dans excel

    worddoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wordapp.Quit
End Sub


Private Sub traitement_champs(worddoc As Word.Document)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim derLigne As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ctrl As Object 'control du contenu

    Set ws = Sheets("Mémoire technique")

    derLigne = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To derLigne
        On Error Resume Next 'si erreur, pas de contrôle de contnu de texte dans word
        
        Debug.Print "champ:" & ws.Cells(i, 3).Value & "valeur:" & ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
        
        For Each ctrl In worddoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value)
            ctrl.Range.Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
        Next ctrl
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to open the document, make changes and then save it unchanged?

Comment: I just saw that you asked nearly the same question yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/q/72035088/16578424). I would have expected, that you update your code according to the the answer you got - but you didn't ... :-(

Comment: Mhh i think i've included all the advices of who answered me: i've modified this "Private Sub traitement_champs(worddoc As Word.Document)" and this "Call traitement_champs(worddoc)"; i've eliminates the 3 first lines and i've tried other think that didn't work and i always have the same error 91. This is why i asked a more specific question and i've said that "2


I've modificated the code following the last advices that I've recived"

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev  i would like to save the document manually

Comment: Hmm - there were already the advises to omit "on error resume next" and to omit `call` ...

Comment: Yes, i've deleted it, i ran the code but i hade a new error on the line "For Each ctrl In worddoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value)
            ctrl.Range.Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value "   That's why i've wrote it again...

Comment: Ignoring errors is not a good idea to get rid of fix errors! You got the error due to ctrl.range.value ... if you change that to .text you won't receive an error.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I'ill work on it this weekend ^^

Answer (score 2):

First of all: you should remove the `on error resume next`!

You don't use call and brackets to call a sub.
Simply use `traitement_champs worddoc`

Make following changes to the sub:
`Dim ctrl as Word.ContentControl` instead of `as Object`

`ctrl.Range.Text = ws.cells(i,4)).value`
(Word ranges only have the text attribute - no value (like Excel))

`worddoc.Close SaveChanges:=False` looks ok - except it doesn't make sense to me, to open and edit the doc and then close it without saving.

Comment: Thank you, but i don't understand this : You don't use call and brackets to call a sub. Simply use traitement_champs worddoc.   You mean that instead of : "traitement_champs(worddoc As Word.Document)" i have to write traitement_champs(worddoc)?

Also, for worddoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
I would like that the word document will open to see the modification and then i will save it manually. But when i generate it, there is no document open

Comment: _You don't use call and brackets to call a sub_ why? It's perfectly valid [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/call-statement)

Comment: @BrakNicku: From your link _If you use either Call syntax to call any intrinsic or user-defined function, the function's return value is discarded._ I suppose this is the source for the error ...

Comment: Your sub-definition is ok. But when calling it from your main routine you only use `traitement_champs worddoc`.  - If you want to check the edited word doc, than remove  `worddoc.Close SaveChanges:=False` and `wordapp.Quit` - otherwise the doc gets closed w/o saving and word app gets closed too.

Comment: There is no _function_ in the code, only subs, so how would it matter?

Comment: @BrakNicku: you are right - in this case it doesn't make a difference.